# whereIn being ignored when filtering a laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to filter a DB query, I am wondering is it possible to use `whereIn` to do this? Currently it is being ignored.

First query is working fine:

```
      $cosmeticTestAllData = DB::table('table')
            ->whereIn('part_number', ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'])
            ->get();
```

Sample Results:

```
Array    (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [part_number] => P1
        [status] => FAIL
        [shipment_channel] => DP
        [created_at] => 2017-01-24 10:25:21
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [part_number] => P2
        [status] => PASS
        [shipment_channel] => DP
        [created_at] => 2018-01-24 10:25:21
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [part_number] => P2
        [status] => FAIL
        [shipment_channel] => DP
        [created_at] => 2018-01-24 10:25:21
    )

 )
```

This query correctly filters the `where` clause but ignores `whereIn`

```
        $fullCount = $cosmeticTestAllData;
        $fullCount->where('created_at', '>', '2018-01-01 00:00:00');
        $fullCount->whereIn('shipment_channel', ['ANYTHING']);
        $fullCount->whereIn('status', ['ANYTHING')];
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($fullCount->all());die;
```

Results:

```
Array    (

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [part_number] => P2
        [status] => PASS
        [shipment_channel] => DP
        [created_at] => 2018-01-24 10:25:21
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [part_number] => P2
        [status] => FAIL
        [shipment_channel] => DP
        [created_at] => 2018-01-24 10:25:21
    )

 )
```

Comment: use `get()` instead of `all()`

Comment: When I use `get()` I get the following error... `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`, Im assuming `get()` is only for DB queries

Comment: why don't you pass the second param of whereIn as an array

Comment: sorry thats a typo in my question, ill update the code now because in the real code the problem still remains even with it as an array.

Comment: Have you checked what Eloquent is actually producing?  Try doing a `dd($fullCount->toSql())` to check the sql being produced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to by trying to treat a collection like a query builder. However most collection operations don't change the collection. Change your code to :

```
$fullCount = $cosmeticTestAllData
       ->where('created_at', '>', '2018-01-01 00:00:00');
       ->whereIn('shipment_channel', ['ANYTHING'])
        ->whereIn('status', ['ANYTHING' ]);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($fullCount->all());die;
```

This way you are chaining the result of each operation to the next operation.

Alternatively you can do those operations on the query builder before you execute the query

Comment: This was the solution, I hadnt got them chained up because there are more conditions in the code that I didnt want to include because it would complicate the question. However it seems I will have to work around that somehow. As soon as I chained them up directly it filtered perfectly, thanks!

I didnt want to do them on the query builder because the filtering is going through a loop and I dont want to be querying the DB within the loop several 100 times

Answer (score 0):

Instead of whereIn, you should try orWhere in the second query.

Comment: Thanks, I had a typo in my code where I wasnt showing that I am looking to query an array in the second query. I have updated it now.  Ill try this anyway and mark as correct if it works. I was trying to avoid this as I though `whereIn()` might be enought

Answer (score 0):

I assume(?) you want something like this:

```
$rows = DB::table('table')
  ->where('created_at', '>', '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
  ->whereIn('part_number', ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'], 'AND')
  ->whereIn('shipment_channel', ['ANYTHING'], 'AND')
  ->whereIn('status', ['ANYTHING'], 'AND')
  ->get();
```

---

Do note that `whereIn` accepts a third(and fourth) argument:

```
/**
 * Add a "where in" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  mixed   $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  bool    $not
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotIn' : 'In';

    // If the value of the where in clause is actually a Closure, we will assume that
    // the developer is using a full sub-select for this "in" statement, and will
    // execute those Closures, then we can re-construct the entire sub-selects.
    if ($values instanceof Closure)
    {
        return $this->whereInSub($column, $values, $boolean, $not);
    }

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'values', 'boolean');

    $this->bindings = array_merge($this->bindings, $values);

    return $this;
}
```

---

Honestly it's not entirely clear what you want to do from the question.